# how can i parse nested json and form a final map with all the key and values from the nested json with mulltiple arrays

Tags: apex, visualforce, custom-controller

How can i Parse through JSON string with multiple subjson inside it in form of arrays and object.
I want to iterate over the json depeding upon the key and value.
Sample JSON:

```js
{
    "licClass": "Driving Licence",
    "licType": "Automobile",
    "attDrive": {
        "SF_LIC_CSUM_EMAIL__c": "n@gmail.com",
        "SF_LIC_CSUM_CONTACT__c": "(536) 242-3423",
        "Name": "16 Nov 2022"
    },
    "addDrive": {
        "SF_LIC_ADD_STATE__c": "Delhi",
        "SF_LIC_ADD_FAX__c": "64328232",
        "SF_LIC_ADD_PINCODE__c": "456324",
        "SF_LIC_ADD_COUNTRY__c": "India",
        "SF_LIC_ADD_CITY__c": "Delhi",
        "SF_LIC_ADD_ADD2__c": "ghsf",
        "SF_LIC_ADD_ADD1__c": "req"
    },
    "bioDrive": {
        "SF_LIC_BIO_EMAIL2__c": "g@gmail.com",
        "SF_LIC_BIO_EMAIL1__c": "d@gmail.com",
        "SF_LIC_BIO_PHONE__c": "(537) 489-5340",
        "SF_LIC_BIO_SSN__c": "653-34-5839",
        "SF_LIC_BIO_MNAME__c": "Nov",
        "SF_LIC_BIO_LNAME__c": "2022",
        "SF_LIC_BIO_FNAME__c": "16 "
    },
    "questions": [
        {
            "AIT_RES_QRES__c": "Yes",
            "AIT_RES_QHID__c": "a0T5g000004eFSXEA2"
        },
        {
            "AIT_RES_QRES__c": "No",
            "AIT_RES_QHID__c": "a0T5g000004eFScEAM"
        },
        {
            "AIT_RES_QRES__c": "No",
            "AIT_RES_QHID__c": "a0T5g000004eFShEAM"
        },
        {
            "AIT_RES_QRES__c": "No",
            "AIT_RES_QHID__c": "a0T5g000004eFSmEAM"
        },
        {
            "AIT_RES_QRES__c": "Yes",
            "AIT_RES_QHID__c": "a0T5g000004eFSrEAM"
        },
        {
            "AIT_RES_QRES__c": "No",
            "AIT_RES_QHID__c": "a0T5g000004eFSwEAM"
        },
        {
            "AIT_RES_QRES__c": "No",
            "AIT_RES_QHID__c": "a0T5g000004eFT1EAM"
        }
    ],
    "responseHistory": [
        {
            "SF_LIC_CONSH_LTYPE__r": {
                "Id": "a0F5g000003A6FqEAK",
                "SF_LIC_LICT_DESC__c": "Automobile",
                "attributes": {
                    "url": "/services/data/v56.0/sobjects/SF_LIC_LICTYPE__c/a0F5g000003A6FqEAK",
                    "type": "SF_LIC_LICTYPE__c"
                }
            },
            "SF_LIC_CONSH_LICCLS__r": {
                "Id": "a0B5g00000tdDNEEA2",
                "Name": "Driving Licence",
                "attributes": {
                    "url": "/services/data/v56.0/sobjects/SF_LIC_LICCLASS__c/a0B5g00000tdDNEEA2",
                    "type": "SF_LIC_LICCLASS__c"
                }
            },
            "SF_LIC_CONSH_LTYPE__c": "a0F5g000003A6FqEAK",
            "SF_LIC_CONSH_LICCLS__c": "a0B5g00000tdDNEEA2",
            "SF_LIC_CONSH_TXT__c": "The State Superintendent is hereby authorized to give any information the Superintendent may have concerning (me) or (us) to any federal, state or municipal agency, or any other organization as referenced in Section of the Law and any person acting on the Superintendents behalf is hereby released from any and all liability of whatever nature by reason of furnishing such information",
            "Id": "a0J5g000003IPNuEAO",
            "attributes": {
                "url": "/services/data/v56.0/sobjects/SF_LIC_CONSHIS__c/a0J5g000003IPNuEAO",
                "type": "SF_LIC_CONSHIS__c"
            }
        }
    ],
    "response": [
        {
            "Id": "a0V5g000004GE3wEAG",
            "SF_LIC_FEE_LICCLS__c": "a0B5g00000tdDNEEA2",
            "SF_LIC_FEE_ACCOUNT_HEAD__c": "Renewal Fees",
            "SF_LIC_FEE_AMT__c": 3400,
            "attributes": {
                "url": "/services/data/v56.0/sobjects/SF_LIC_FEE__c/a0V5g000004GE3wEAG",
                "type": "SF_LIC_FEE__c"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to parse this json automatically depending on the key and its value using recursion.

Answer (score 0):

1. Method 1 You need to create a chain of inner classes and then use the JSON.deserializeType method to deserialize this
2. The 2nd easiest way is to use the Parser, Link to the documentation https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_json_jsonparser.htm
3. Since your response is too big it would be easier to use a parser rather than creating a chain of inner classes

Answer (score 0):

I was thinking something like

```apex
map<string,object> jsonp = (map<string,object>)system.JSON.deserializeUntyped(jsoninput);
```

then i get the keys in a map

then using for loop can i iterate over the keyset of the json and form a final map which has all the key and values.

this will help in parsing of anytype of json in future and converting it into a final map with all the key and values in it.

we can ignore the duplicate keys and values in my json .

Answer (score -2):

you can easily use a tool like https://json2apex.herokuapp.com/ to get you 90% of the way.

Answer (score -2):

To parse through a JSON string with multiple sub-JSON objects inside it, you can use the json module in Python. The `json.loads()` method parses a JSON string and returns a Python dictionary. Once you have the JSON object as a dictionary, you can iterate over it using a for loop. Here's an example:

```python
import json
json_string = '{"licClass": "Driving Licence", "licType": "Automobile", ...}'
json_obj = json.loads(json_string)
for key, value in json_obj.items():
    # Do something with the key and value
```

In the example above, the `json_obj` variable will contain the JSON object as a Python dictionary. The for loop will iterate over the key-value pairs in the dictionary, allowing you to access each key and value. You can then do whatever you need to do with the key and value, such as print them or use them in some other way.

Comment: This question is about Apex, not Python